# Why is running AJAX queries in parallel much slower than doing serially?

Tags: javascript, c#, angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I have a page where angular uses ng-init to run a few ajax call's to populate the page. The page took about 1s to load, and I found that strange so I did a little digging.

This was the original code (minus error handling)

```
accountService.roles(null, function (response) {
    $scope.roles = response;
});
masterDataService.getallparties(null, function (response) {
    $scope.parties = response;
});
accountService.users($scope.searchFilter, function (response) {
    $scope.users = response;
});
```

Now I did a rewrite using serial calls instead of parallel:

```
accountService.roles(null, function (response) {
    $scope.roles = response;
    masterDataService.getallparties(null, function (response) {
        $scope.parties = response;
        accountService.users($scope.searchFilter, function (response) {
            $scope.users = response;
        });
    });
});
```

And voila, the page now loads in about 100ms.

Is this expected? Is there something on my server (IIS / MVC 4.6) that's wrong?

EDIT: added screenshots
[image]
[image]

[image]

Comment: Is the services all returning a callback (that assigns $scope.params?). It might be because of angular. Which version of angular are you using?

Comment: In this case all of them uses: $http({ method: 'GET', and all of them assigns to $scope.param on success. I'm using angular 1.5.8

Comment: Does page load average out at 1s (ie did you disable cache on every page load) respectively for both cases?

Comment: I disabled cache on every page load yes, and it seems like the parallel one made each request take 500ms longer (so first one 30ms, next 530ms and last one 1030ms), where 30 varies from 15 to 45

Comment: Modern browsers should be able to leverage 4-8 simultaneous requests (so I doubt it's just an IE thing)

Comment: Depending on the tasks it could be a memory issue. If several big requests run on the same thread (requested by same session) simultaneously, then the server, trying to process all requests at once, might run out of memory. This would lead to more Garbage Collection cycles and such, which would eat time. Stuff like file locks, session locks and database connection might compound this issue.

Comment: Also when running serially, the request takes from 15-45 ms each, so to me it seems like something is adding 500ms when in parallell

Comment: @EmilS.Jørgensen this is run on a machine with 64GB of ram, at the time I tested this, there where less than 25% in use. Also these requests should be micro requests.

Comment: You might be having some db locks? accessing same stuff on server or things like that?

Comment: @tanmay these are basically select * from queries, targeting 3 different tables with absolutely no other activity in that DB so I doubt it. SQL server profiler also shows that the queries takes less than 5ms

Comment: It could also be Angulars [Dirty Checking](https://www.quora.com/What-is-dirty-checking-in-AngularJs-and-how-does-it-work) that eats processing power between the calls. If you have big data in your scope, even though you didn't touch it Angular will still be evaluating it for changes. Or maybe the browser renders a frame after each request when not in serial, which takes resources and time. In the network tab in  the developer pane, are there any difference in the execution time of the AJAX calls?

Comment: @devzero you can go through timeline/profiling from devtools to see whether if it's angular related issue at all, maybe you can post some results in question too

Comment: @tanmay I've adde timeline from chrome

Comment: can you profile C# for us thanks;

Answer (score 0):

Browsers limit the number of simultaneous requests per domain. For Internet Explorer, this value is configurable in the Registry and is set by default to 2. See https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/282402/how-do-i-configure-internet-explorer-to-download-more-than-two-files-at-one-time.

Comment: Why would that make parallel slower than serial? Worst case (only 1 request per domain) should force them into serial request

Comment: how would that make 1 at a time requests faster than parallel - genuine question, I'm not questioning your answer at all

Comment: I know, I don't have an explanation, I just thought it was worth bringing this.